# SQL question - how to output using iterative date logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions, recursive-query

I have the following sample table (provided with single ID for simplicity - need to perform the same logic across all IDs)

```
ID    Visit_date
-----------------
ABC   8/7/2019
ABC   9/10/2019
ABC   9/12/2019
ABC   10/1/2019
ABC   10/1/2019
ABC   10/8/2019
ABC   10/15/2019
ABC   10/17/2019
ABC   10/24/2019
```

Here is what I need to get the sample output

1. Mark the first visit as 1 in the "new_visit" column
2. Compare the subsequent dates with the 1st date until it exceeds 21 days condition. Example Sep 10 is compared to Aug 7 and it doesn’t fall within 21 days of Aug 7, therefore this is considered as another new_visit, so mark new_visit as 1
3. Then we compare Sep 10 with the subsequent dates with 21 days criteria and mark all of them as follow_up of Sep 10 visit. Eg. Sep 12, Oct 1 are within 21 days of Sep 10; hence they are considered as follow up visits, so mark "follow_up" as 1
4. When the subsequent date exceeds 21 days criteria of the previous new visit (e.g. Oct 8 compared to Sep 10) then Oct 8 will be considered a new visit & mark "New_visit" as 1 and the subsequent dates will be compared against Oct 8

Sample Output :

```
Dates   New_Visit   Follow_up
-----------------------------
8/7/2019    1   
9/10/2019   1   
9/12/2019               1
10/1/2019               1
10/1/2019               1
10/8/2019   1   
10/15/2019              1
10/17/2019              1
10/24/2019              1
```

Comment: PLease edit the question and tag with the proper database platform. thanks

Comment: So, are you saying, if someone visits every day, for 22 days, the 22nd day would be a "new" visit?

Comment: Also, helpful hint, please don't use formats for `M/d/yyyy` for dates; it makes consuming the data really difficult.

Comment: This question has been answered. Thanks a lot GMB & Gordon!!

Comment: Hey @Larnu, yes - you are correct!

Comment: @Dale K - I tried solving using windows function (unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) however that didn’t work in this case since instead of unbounded preceding, the upper bound logically would have to be dynamically allocated each time. Nevertheless, the solution proposed by GMB & Gordon below of using recursive CTE  resolves it. Thanks!!

Comment: Dale K - Ok, got it.

Comment: Thanks for your question @Somy. Could you inlclude a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi David, The question has been answered already so I believe we can close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive query for this.

You would enumerate the rows, then walk through the dataset by ascending date, while keeping track of the first visit date of each group; when the interval since the last first visit exceeds 21 days, the date of the first visit resets, and a new group starts.

```
with 
    data as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by date) rn 
        from mtytable t
    ),
    cte as (
        select id, visit_date, visit_date first_visit_date
        from data
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select c.id, d.visit_date, case when d.visit_date > datead(day, 21, c.first_visit_date) then d.visit_date else c.first_visit_date end
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.id = c.id and d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select
    id,
    date,
    case when visit_date = first_visit_date then 1 else 0 end as is_new
    case when visit_date = first_visit_date then 0 else 1 end as is_follow_up
from cte
```

If a patient may have more than 100 visits, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Comment: This is great!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive CTE to handle this.  This is the idea, although the exact syntax might vary by database:

```
with recursive t as (
      select id, date,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from yourtable
     ),
     recursive cte as (
      select id, date, visit_start as date, 1 as is_new_visit
      from t
      where id = 1
      union all
      select cte.id, t.date, 
             (case when t.date < visit_start + interval '21 day'
                   then cte.visit_start else t.date
              end) as visit_start,
             (case when t.date < cte.visit_start + interval '21 say'
                   then 0 else 1
              end) as is_new_visit
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id = cte.id and t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
where is_new_visit = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!! I got the idea from your response. However, I used the query shared by GMB since syntactically It’s closer to the platform I am using. However, it’s based on the same principle/logic which you shared. Thank you!!

Comment: @Somy . . . If you had tagged your question correctly, you would have had an answer more quickly.

Comment: Lesson learnt of course !! But that said, I got the answer within few mins, so it’s great!!